# How to change specific values in dictionary regardless of the keys in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I change the values in a dictionary in python regardless of the keys? If we take the following dictionary for our example:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}
```

Now I want to manipulate the dictionary in the way that all the values *2* will be changed into *3* so the output would be:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 3, 'e': 1}
```

I am sure the problem is very basic, but I somehow haven't managed to find the answer online.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do it with dict comprehension, ``{k : 3 if v == 2 else v for k, v in d.items()}``

Comment: Maybe you should use a different data structure.

Comment: I needed to use a dictionary and the first solution by @bigboutny was also the one a used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [338]: d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}

In [339]: for k,v in d.items():
     ...:     if v == 2:
     ...:         d[k] = 3
     ...:

In [340]: d
Out[340]: {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 0, 'd': 3, 'e': 1}
```